# How do I check a value in a boolean List?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this List: `List<bool> values = new List<bool>();`

Filled with:
`True,True,False,True,False,False,True`

When I do this:
`int amountTrue = values.Count(v => true);`
it returns `7`. That's just the amount of values in the List. I think it checks if the value exists, but this is not what I want.

How do I get the amount of `True` values in the List by using `Count` or any other chainable method? I know I can loop through it but I think this could be done easier.

Comment: Try `int amountTrue = values.Count(v => v);`

Comment: "I think it checks if the value exists, but this is not what I want." No, it checks the number of elements for which your predicate returns true. Now your predicate returns true regardless of the value of the element... which is why it's effectively the original count.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Count` method can take a predicate, which is basically a method that returns a boolean. In this case, the `Count` method is counting the number of items that "pass" the predicate. What you were doing is saying "for each item, check if `true` is true", which is, obviously, always true. What you want to do is check if each *value* is true, which you can do like so:

```
values.Count(v => v);
```

or longhand

```
values.Where(v => v).Count();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<bool> values = new List<bool>() { true, true, false, true, false, false, true };

Console.WriteLine(values.Count(v => v == true)); //output : 4
Console.WriteLine(values.Count(v => v == false)); //output : 3

//equivalent
Console.WriteLine(values.Count(v => v)); //v == true, output : 4
Console.WriteLine(values.Count(v => !v)); //v == false, output : 3
```

Console output :

4

3

4

3

Answer (score 0):

A list of boolean doesn't contain relevant data such as keys or values for other queries, you might just want to use an alternative solution like incrementing integers. With your current solution, the list solution, when the list will grow over thousands of values it will take more cpu time to count all the elements and more memory to store all the elements.

Alternative solution :

```
int nbTrue = 0; // choose a significant name
int nbFalse = 0; // choose a significant name

nbTrue++;
nbFalse++;
```

Answer (score 0):

var count = values.Count(v => true == v)

Answer (score 0):

values.Count(v => v); returns result according to value of v
values.Count(v => true); always return true.